# mysql node.js query error(undefined)? how to fix it

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

The problem is that when the second request is executed, it returns undefined, i.e. for some reason, it does not see the result of the second request. It should work like this: We make the first request, and if there are less than two lines, then we execute the second request. What could be the error? how to fix it

```js
let arr = [name1, name2 /* ... */];
let ipObject = { Objects: [] };
arr.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  connection.query("select 1 from i.goa where object_name = ?", elem, (err, rows) => {
    // console.log (rows.length);
    if (rows.length < 2) {
      //  console.log (elem);
      connection.query(
        "SELECT ip_adress FROM i.gs where server_kod=(SELECT server_kod FROM i.gol where object_kod =(SELECT object_kod FROM i.goa where  object_name=?))",

        elem,
        (err, rows2) => {
          console.log(elem);
          console.log(rows2);
          if (undefined !== rows2 && rows2.length > 0) {
            // if(rows2.length>0 ){
            ipObject.Objects.push({ objectName: elem, serverIp: rows2[0].ip_adress });
          }
          i++;
          if (i > count) {
            cb(JSON.stringify(ipObject));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(ipObject));
            //  fs.writeFileSync('e.json',JSON.stringify(ipObject),'utf8');
          }
        },
      );
    } else if (rows.length >= 2) {
      ipObject.Objects.push({ objectName: elem, serverIp: "ошибка" });
      cb(JSON.stringify(ipObject));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Add the complete error message to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably bumping into asynchronicity issues here.

Refactoring things to use async/await and `Promise.map()`, maybe this is closer to what you want:

```js
function queryP(connection, query, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, params, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

async function queryForName(connection, objectName) {
  const rows = await queryP(connection, "select 1 from i.goa where object_name = ?", objectName);
  if (rows.length >= 2) {
    return { objectName, serverIp: "ошибка" };
  }
  const rows2 = await queryP(connection, "SELECT ip_adress FROM i.gs where server_kod=(SELECT server_kod FROM i.gol where object_kod =(SELECT object_kod FROM i.goa where object_name=?))", objectName);
  if (rows2.length > 0) {
    return { objectName, serverIp: rows2[0].ip_adress };
  }
  return { objectName, serverIp: "???" };
}

async function queryForNames(connection, names) {
  return {
    Objects: await Promise.all(names.map((name) => queryForName(connection, name))),
  };
}

// could as well be `const resultObject = await queryForNames(...)` if you're calling this from an async function.
queryForNames(connection, [name1, name2]).then((resultObject) => {
  console.log(resultObject);
});
```